# Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x42)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in Swift programmation and I receive this error when I run my little program (I just want to list the data into tableview). So here's what I've done so far:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{

  let identifier = "Cell"

var cell : TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as TableViewCell

if(cell == nil)

{

    cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as TableViewCell;

}

  println("hii \(arrDict)")

  let str : NSString = arrDict[indexPath.row]  as NSString //Here i am getting bad instruction

cell.textlbl.text = str

return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)

{

    println("\(indexPath.row)!.Cell \(arrDict[indexPath.row])!")

}
```

Comment: what the result u get here println("hii \(arrDict)")

Comment: i am getting arrDict as Response data in the form of array.

Comment: Which line you getting this Bad_Access

Comment: Do you get: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value  as well?

Comment: no i am getting Bad code instruction in let str : NSString = arrDict[indexPath.row]  as NSString

Comment: @ Kathiravan G let str : NSString = arrDict[indexPath.row]  as NSString

Comment: @  Anbu.Karthik i am getting ArrDict as ArrDict:(
        (
        "javascript_tutorial"
    )
)

Answer (score 0):

There must be a few reasons.

1- You not set your identifier cell.

[image]

2 - Make sure no warning message.

[image]